# No se me habilita el botón aunque el formulario está completo

Tags: jquery, html5

Estoy validando un formulario en el que todos los campos deben ser requeridos. Por esto, cree un script con jQuery en el que valida todos los campos. En  teoría, debería habilitarse el botón de enviar en cuanto todos los campos tengan valor maor a 0 o vacío:

```js
var nuevo = 1;

function agregarAutores() {

  var campo = '<div id="autor' + nuevo + '"><br><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="autoresArticulos[]" placeholder="Nombre completo del autor..." required autocomplete="off"></div><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><button type="button" class="btn-rojo rippler rippler-default" onclick="eliminarAutor(' + nuevo + ');" style="padding: .4em 1.1em;">-</button></div></div></div>';

  $("#contenedorAutores").append(campo);

  nuevo++;

};

function eliminarAutor(id) {

  $("#autor" + id).remove();

}

$(document).on("keyup", "#formularioArticulo input", function(e) {

  var formulario = $(this).parents("#formularioArticulo");

  var input = validarInputs(formulario);

  var select = validarSelect(formulario);

  if (input && select) {

    $("#subirArticulo").removeAttr('disabled');

  } else {

    $("#subirArticulo").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  }

});

$(document).on("change", "#formularioArticulo select", function(e) {

  var formulario = $(this).parents("#formularioArticulo");

  var input = validarInputs(formulario);

  var select = validarSelect(formulario);

  if (input && select) {

    $("#subirArticulo").removeAttr('disabled');

  } else {

    $("#subirArticulo").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  }

});

$(document).on("focus", "input, select", function(e) {

  $(this).css('border-color', '#CED4DA');

});

function validarInputs(objeto) {

  objeto.find("input").each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() <= 0 || $(this).val() == "") {

      $(this).css('border-color', '#EF3109');

    } else {

      return true;

    }

  });

}

function validarSelect(objeto) {

  objeto.find("select").each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() <= 0 || $(this).val() == "") {

      $(this).css('border-color', '#EF3109');

    } else {

      return true;

    }

  });

}
```

```css
#formularioArticulo {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

button {
  padding: .6em 1.1em;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #3B3B3B;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #3B3B3B;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #3B3B3B;
  outline: none;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border: none;
  opacity: .6;
}

button:not(:disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

button:disabled {
  opacity: .6;
}

.btn-rojo {
  background-color: #EF3109;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-amarillo {
  background-color: #F5C518;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-azul {
  background-color: #1976D2;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-send {
  background-color: #2A8D32;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formularioArticulo" method="POST">


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="nombreRegistrador">Nombre completo:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreRegistrador" id="nombreRegistrador" placeholder="Nombre completo de quién registra el artículo..." required autocomplete="off">

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="apellidoRegistrador">Apellido completo:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidoRegistrador" id="apellidoRegistrador" placeholder="Apellido completo de quién registra el artículo..." required autocomplete="off">

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="correoRegistrador">Correo electrónico:</label>

    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correoRegistrador" id="correoRegistrador" placeholder="Correo electrónico de quién registra el artículo..." required autocomplete="off">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">El correo electrónico será la primer vía de contacto entre el comité editorial y el Registrador.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="celularRegistrador">Número de contacto:</label>

    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="celularRegistrador" id="celularRegistrador" placeholder="Número de contacto de quién registra el artículo..." required autocomplete="off">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">El número de contacto será una vía alterna de contacto.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="institucionArticulo">Institución que representa el artículo:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="institucionArticulo" id="institucionArticulo" placeholder="Institución que representa el artículo..." required autocomplete="off">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">Ingrese el nombre completo de la institución que representa este artículo.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group" id="contenedorAutores">

    <label for="autoresArticulos">Ingresa el nombre de los autores:</label>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="autoresArticulos[]" id="autoresArticulos" placeholder="Nombre completo del autor..." required autocomplete="off">

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

        <button type="button" class="btn-amarillo rippler rippler-default" onclick="agregarAutores();" style="padding: .4em 1.1em;">+</button>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="areaArticulo">Área del conocimiento del artículo:</label>

    <select class="form-control" name="areaArticulo" id="areaArticulo">

      <option value="">Selecciona un área de conocimiento</option>


      <option value="Agronomía, veterinaria y afines">Agronomía, veterinaria y afines</option>


      <option value="Bellas artes">Bellas artes</option>


      <option value="Ciencias de la educación">Ciencias de la educación</option>


      <option value="Ciencias de la salud">Ciencias de la salud</option>


      <option value="Ciencias sociales y humanas">Ciencias sociales y humanas</option>


      <option value="Economía, administración, contaduría y afines">Economía, administración, contaduría y afines</option>


      <option value="Matemáticas y ciencias naturales">Matemáticas y ciencias naturales</option>


    </select>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="documentoArticulo">Ingrese el artículo:</label>

    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="documentoArticulo" id="documentoArticulo" required>

    <small class="form-text text-muted">El artículo debe tener el <a href="../archivos/plantilla/Guia_Articulo.docx" download="Plantilla formato artículos.docx">formato estipulado</a> en las <a href="../nosotros/" target="_BLANK">instrucciones</a>.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="button-group">

    <button type="submit" id="subirArticulo" class="btn-send rippler rippler-default" disabled>Enviar Artículo</button>

  </div>


</form>
```

¿Cómo podría realizar esa validación para cuando todos los campos estén llenos, habilitar en botón?

Comment: ambas funciones de validar dan resultados "undefined" por lo que es normal que no funcionen. Estoy echándole un ojo a ver cómo resolverlo

Comment: ¿En serio? No había caído en cuenta. Mucas gracias. Estaré atento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, debes crear unas variables que acumulen el estado de todos los campos.

Las he creado como globales, y he eliminado los return de los métodos.

A partir de ahí, si uno de los métodos detecta algún error, pone la variable correspondiente a false.

Si por el contrario no encuentra ningún error, pone el valor a true.

Una vez comprobadas las dos partes, sí que podemos comprobar las variables globales para modificar el botón.

```js
var nuevo = 1;
var input = false;
var select = false;

function agregarAutores() {

  var campo = '<div id="autor' + nuevo + '"><br><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="autoresArticulos[]" placeholder="Nombre completo del autor..." required autocomplete="off"></div><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><button type="button" class="btn-rojo rippler rippler-default" onclick="eliminarAutor(' + nuevo + ');" style="padding: .4em 1.1em;">-</button></div></div></div>';

  $("#contenedorAutores").append(campo);

  nuevo++;

};

function eliminarAutor(id) {

  $("#autor" + id).remove();

}

$(document).on("keyup", "#formularioArticulo input", function(e) {

  var formulario = $("#formularioArticulo");
  
  validarInputs(formulario);
  validarSelect(formulario);
  updateButton();


});

$("input[type=file]").change(function(){
         var formulario = $("#formularioArticulo");
  
        validarInputs(formulario);
        validarSelect(formulario);
        updateButton();
 });

$(document).on("change", "#formularioArticulo select", function(e) {

  var formulario = $("#formularioArticulo");
  
  validarInputs(formulario);
  validarSelect(formulario);
  updateButton();

});

$(document).on("focus", "input, select", function(e) {

  $(this).css('border-color', '#CED4DA');

});

function validarInputs(objeto) {

  var error = false;
  objeto.find("input").each(function() {
  
  
    if ($(this).val() <= 0 || $(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).css('border-color', '#EF3109');
      error = true;
    }
  });

  if (error == false) 
  {
    input = true;
  } 
  else {
  input = false
  };

}

function validarSelect(objeto) {

  var error = false;
  objeto.find("select").each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() <= 0 || $(this).val() == "") {

      $(this).css('border-color', '#EF3109');
      error = true;

    }
    if (!error) {
      select = true;
      
    } else{select = false};
  });
}

function updateButton() {
  if (input && select) {
  
    $("#subirArticulo").removeAttr('disabled','');
  } else {
    $("#subirArticulo").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  }
 }
```

```css
#formularioArticulo {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

button {
  padding: .6em 1.1em;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #3B3B3B;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #3B3B3B;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #3B3B3B;
  outline: none;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border: none;
}

button:not(:disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

button[disabled="disabled"] {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.btn-rojo {
  background-color: #EF3109;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-amarillo {
  background-color: #F5C518;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-azul {
  background-color: #1976D2;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-send {
  background-color: #2A8D32;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formularioArticulo" method="POST">


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="nombreRegistrador">Nombre completo:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreRegistrador" id="nombreRegistrador" placeholder="Nombre completo de quién registra el artículo..." required autocomplete="off">

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="apellidoRegistrador">Apellido completo:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidoRegistrador" id="apellidoRegistrador" placeholder="Apellido completo de quién registra el artículo..." required autocomplete="off">

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="correoRegistrador">Correo electrónico:</label>

    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correoRegistrador" id="correoRegistrador" placeholder="Correo electrónico de quién registra el artículo..." required autocomplete="off">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">El correo electrónico será la primer vía de contacto entre el comité editorial y el Registrador.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="celularRegistrador">Número de contacto:</label>

    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="celularRegistrador" id="celularRegistrador" placeholder="Número de contacto de quién registra el artículo..." required autocomplete="off">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">El número de contacto será una vía alterna de contacto.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="institucionArticulo">Institución que representa el artículo:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="institucionArticulo" id="institucionArticulo" placeholder="Institución que representa el artículo..." required autocomplete="off">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">Ingrese el nombre completo de la institución que representa este artículo.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group" id="contenedorAutores">

    <label for="autoresArticulos">Ingresa el nombre de los autores:</label>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="autoresArticulos[]" id="autoresArticulos" placeholder="Nombre completo del autor..." required autocomplete="off">

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

        <button type="button" class="btn-amarillo rippler rippler-default" onclick="agregarAutores();" style="padding: .4em 1.1em;">+</button>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="areaArticulo">Área del conocimiento del artículo:</label>

    <select class="form-control" name="areaArticulo" id="areaArticulo">

      <option value="">Selecciona un área de conocimiento</option>


      <option value="Agronomía, veterinaria y afines">Agronomía, veterinaria y afines</option>


      <option value="Bellas artes">Bellas artes</option>


      <option value="Ciencias de la educación">Ciencias de la educación</option>


      <option value="Ciencias de la salud">Ciencias de la salud</option>


      <option value="Ciencias sociales y humanas">Ciencias sociales y humanas</option>


      <option value="Economía, administración, contaduría y afines">Economía, administración, contaduría y afines</option>


      <option value="Matemáticas y ciencias naturales">Matemáticas y ciencias naturales</option>


    </select>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="documentoArticulo">Ingrese el artículo:</label>

    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="documentoArticulo" id="documentoArticulo" required>

    <small class="form-text text-muted">El artículo debe tener el <a href="../archivos/plantilla/Guia_Articulo.docx" download="Plantilla formato artículos.docx">formato estipulado</a> en las <a href="../nosotros/" target="_BLANK">instrucciones</a>.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="button-group">

    <button type="submit" id="subirArticulo" disabled="disabled" class="btn-send rippler rippler-default" disabled>Enviar Artículo</button>

  </div>


</form>
```

**EDIT**

He cambiado el CSS para añadir una opacidad diferente al que tenga el atributo disabled

Por otra parte, he añadido un evento nuevo para el caso del fileinput, que no comprobabas.

Ahora, tanto en el select como en el file input, como en el resto de inputs, funciona el evento correctamente y sí se valida.

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Hola. Lo probé aquí en el snippet y en mi localhost y sigue sin funcionar. El botón no realiza ninguna acción.

Comment: Hola @Santiago, en el snippet que te he pasado el botón se activa.. Qué es lo que tienes diferente en tu localhost??? Si el problema es diferente, deberías plantear una nueva pregunta y aceptar esta si el problema de que el botón no se activa ya está resuelto

Comment: En serio. Ni aquí, ni en mi localhost me funciona.

Comment: @SantiagoCorreaAguirreSanmar echa un vistazo a la nueva solución. Había un par de cosillas que corregir, ahora va perfecta. disculpa el error!!

Comment: Ahora sí. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro! Fuerza y salud!!